# Combinatorics problem involving selection of digits

Tags: combinatorics

How many 10-digit decimal sequences using $(0, 1, 2, . . . , 9)$ are there
in which digits 3, 4, 5, 6 all appear?

What I did to solve this question was this.

The number of ways to select $3,4,5,6$ from $10$ numbers is

$$\binom{10}{4}$$

and the ways to fill the rest of the digits would be $10^{10-4}=10^{6}$

So I thought that the total number of possibilities would

$$\binom{10}{4}*10^{6}$$

I was wondering what is wrong with this reasoning?

The answer that you get using inclusion-exclusion principle is different.

Comment: user262291:  Do not use vague and useless titles, such as "What's wrong?" or "Help me" etc. as your title should help others in the future find the topic and content.

Answer (score 2):

First, your description of $10 \choose 4$ is wrong because there is only one way to select specifically those digits.  What you really should be saying is there are $10 \choose 4$ ways to select the positions for the $3,4,5,6$.  Second you should multiply by $4!$ for the orders of $3,4,5,6$  Third, you are double counting numbers that have additional copies of $3,4,5,$ and/or $6$.  For example $3456311111$ is counted twice, once when you count the first $3$ in the specified $3,4,5,6$ and again when you count the second $3$